# I want to change the whole style on click with angular

Tags: angularjs, function, button, styles

I'm trying to change the style of a div on click with angular, what am I doing wrong?
Code from index.cshtml:

```
<div ng-click="loadAllBooks()" ng-class="{{tagAll}}">Wszystkie</div>
        <div ng-click="loadAllAudiobooks()" ng-class="{{tagAudiobook}}">Audiobooki</div>
        <div ng-click="loadAllEbooks()"  ng-class="{{tagEbook}}">E-booki</div>
```

In my stylesheet I have styles for classes tagged and untagged

And from my javascript file (the function that changes the class in on the bottom of the code):

```
$scope.loadAllBooks = function () {
    $scope.books = [];
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.changeTagStyle(0);
    $http.get("/Home/GetAllBooks").
        then(function (response) {
            $scope.books = response.data;
        }).catch(function (response) {
            $scope.books = [];
        }).finally(function () {
            console.log("Done");
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
};

$scope.loadAllAudiobooks = function () {
    $scope.books = [];
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.changeTagStyle(1);
    $http.get("/Home/GetAllAudiobooks").
        then(function (response) {
            $scope.books = response.data;
        }).catch(function (response) {
            $scope.books = [];
        }).finally(function () {
            console.log("Done");
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
};

$scope.loadAllEbooks = function () {
    $scope.books = [];
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.changeTagStyle(2);
    $http.get("/Home/GetAllEbooks").
        then(function (response) {
            $scope.books = response.data;
        }).catch(function (response) {
            $scope.books = [];
        }).finally(function () {
            console.log("Done");
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
};

$scope.changeTagStyle = function (id) {
    $scope.tagAll = "untagged";
    $scope.tagAudiobook = "untagged";
    $scope.tagEbook = "untagged";

    if ($scope.id === 0)
        $scope.tagAll = "tagged";
    else if ($scope.id === 1)
        $scope.tagAudiobook = "tagged";
    else if ($scope.id === 2)
        $scope.tagEbook = "tagged";
};
```

The function loadAllBooks is launched on start, and it should run changeTagStyle

Comment: This should be tagged <angularjs>, not <angular>

Comment: Sorry, changed it

Comment: Really not clear what specific problem is

Comment: Change `$scope.id == 0` and others to `id == 0`, you are passing *id* as a parameter, it's not bounded to scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to change your code to (you have to remove curly braces as ng-class is angularjs directive it will recognize your variable) :

```
<div ng-click="loadAllBooks()" ng-class="tagAll">Wszystkie</div>
    <div ng-click="loadAllAudiobooks()" ng-class="tagAudiobook">Audiobooki</div>
    <div ng-click="loadAllEbooks()"  ng-class="tagEbook">E-booki</div>
```

Comment: great ! So this was the issue ?

Comment: It looks like yes

Comment: You can accept my answer if it helped :) upvote would also be appreciated :)